# Undefined variable: stations in view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have undefined variable and it doesn't call variable.

I get missing argument 1 error when I try accessing a page. This is my code.

Part of the view:

```
@foreach($stations as $station)
    <span> {{ $stations->station }} </span>
@endforeach
```

Controller:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $stations = DB::table('stations')->pluck('station');
    return view('configuration.configuration', $stations);
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('configuration/', 'ConfigurationController@show');
```

Comment: `@foreach($stations as $station)
    <span> {{ $station->station }} </span>
@endforeach` this one corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below code in controller

```
public function show($id)
{
    $stations = DB::table('stations')->pluck('station');
    $data['stations'] = $stations;
    return view('configuration.configuration', $data);
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach($stations as $station)
    <span> {{ $station->station }} </span>
@endforeach
```

**You are directly passing the array value to view. It will not work like that. You have to assign the values to an array index and then call that index like `$index_name` in view. Then it will give you the desired output**

Comment: @OunknownO, Try this `<span> {{ $station }} </span>`

Comment: jup it works now. Now I have two questions why this work for user controller 
        return view('users.viewUser')
        ->with('user', User::find($id)); my question is why didn't it work for stations like that?

Comment: @OunknownO, Didn't get the idea

Comment: i have that code above in my users controller and it works fine(it returns users but when I tried that code(of course change the name of views and variable names) but it didn't work(it also was giving undeclared variable error)

Comment: I think you have to mention the code in a new question. it is not a good habit to ask and give answer in comments.

Answer (score 2):

or

```
public function show($id)
{
    $stations = DB::table('stations')->pluck('station');
    return view('configuration.configuration')->with(stations);
}
```

if you dont want to neft your $station into unused $data

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code in controller:-

```
public function show($id)
{
$stations = DB::table('stations')->pluck('station');
return view('configuration.configuration', compact('stations'));
}
```